# Missing copied text from excel to word bookmark

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy text from excel cell to word specific location. These places are bookmarks place on individual pages in word doc.

Below the vba works but sometimes the copied text is not there. Sometime it misses 3, sometimes 5 and sometimes only 1 bookmark. The missing text is every time different for given bookmark. I have tried to slow down the vba by `Application.Wait()` but this didn't help. It seems the communication excel-word is not 100%. I don't have other explanation for this.

Here is the vba:

```
rArray1 = Array("s145:f145","s146:f146",.......)
rArray2 = Array("s155:f155","s156:f156",.......)

For i = 0 To 2

Application.ScreenUpdating=False
Application.EnableEvents=False
   Err.Clear
If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp=CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")
Word.Visible=True
WordApp.Activate

myDoc.SaveAs Filename:=("C:/.........")

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Doc").Select

Set texttb1 = ActiveSheet.Range(rArray1(i))
texttb1.Copy
myDoc.Bookmarks("Bookmark01").Select
myDoc.Bookmarks("Bookmark01").Range.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText

Set texttb2 = ActiveSheet.Range(rArray2(i))
texttb2.Copy
myDoc.Bookmarks("Bookmark02").Select
myDoc.Bookmarks("Bookmark02").Range.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText

....
....
Next i
```

I'm vba beginner as you can see. I'm sure the vba can be greatly improved. However why the copied text is missing sometimes? Thank you.

Comment: Your for loop is...strange. You recreate the wordapp inside it, but not the word doc. Why? I'd start by cleaning that up. Put everything outside that doesn't need redoing every time. Like `screenupdating`, `enableevents`, `wordapp.`. Also, what is your `Word`? In `Word.Visible`. It's supposed to be `Wordapp.Visible`, no? Clean up that code a bit, see if that helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as for your question, my foundings are that key is to add

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

right after each `.PasteSpecial` statement, to clear Excel data from the clipboard

as to the overall code setting, let me propose what follows

```
Option Explicit

Public WordApp As Object ' declare a public variable to hold Word application reference
Public WordClose As Boolean ' declare a public variable to hold what to do of Word application before the macro runs

Sub main()
Dim rArray1 As Variant, rArray2 As Variant
Dim i As Long

Dim myDoc As Word.Document

rArray1 = Array("s145:f145", "s146:f146")
rArray2 = Array("s155:f155", "s156:f156")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

GetWord ' have the procedure "GetWord" take care of getting a running instance of Word or set a new one

Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="C:\MyFiles\MyDoc.doc") '<== set the proper path and name document. you may want to wrap this in a function to handle possible errors ("file not found", etc,...)

For i = LBound(rArray1) To UBound(rArray1) 'Warning: we're assuming rArray1 and rArray1 have the same length

    Call MyPaste(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Doc").Range(rArray1(i)), myDoc, "Bookmark01")

    Call MyPaste(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Doc").Range(rArray2(i)), myDoc, "Bookmark02")

Next i

LeaveWord myDoc ' have the procedure "LeaveWord" take care of leaving Word properly and accordingly to what previuously defined

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub


Sub GetWord()

WordClose = False
On Error Resume Next
Set WordApp = GetObject(, class:="Word.Application") 'try and get an already running instance of Word
If WordApp Is Nothing Then
    Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application") ' since there was no Word running instance, create a new instance of it
    Word.Documents.Add
    WordClose = True ' after the macro runs, the new Word instance will be quit unless otherwise specified in "LeaveWord" sub calling arguments
End If
On Error GoTo 0

WordApp.Visible = False  ' for speeding it up, make Word "invisible"

End Sub


Sub LeaveWord(myDoc As Word.Document, Optional keepOpen As Variant)
' farewell to Word
' it handles both Word and variables connected to it

If IsMissing(keepOpen) Then keepOpen = Not WordClose ' default is closing Word if an instance of it has been created specifically opened for this macro

If Not WordApp Is Nothing Then
    With WordApp
        If Not keepOpen Then
            .Quit
        Else
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .Visible = True
            .Activate
        End If
    End With
    Set myDoc = Nothing
    Set WordApp = Nothing
End If

End Sub


Sub MyPaste(excelRng As Range, wordDoc As Word.Document, bookMarkName As String)

If wordDoc.Bookmarks.Exists(bookMarkName) Then

    On Error GoTo errlabel
    excelRng.Copy
    wordDoc.Bookmarks(bookMarkName).Range.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText

    Application.CutCopyMode = False '<== clear Excel data from the clipboard

    Exit Sub

errlabel:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    ' ... whatevere else you may need to do to handle/properly notify the error
    On Error GoTo 0

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks good. I will apply your remarks tomorrow. I'm confident that this should help.